# powershell replace command if line starts with a specific character

Tags: powershell, if-statement, replace

I have a text file that I would like to read and do some replacements using powershell only if the line starts with a specific character.

SAy i want to change all the dash (-) to an 'x' if and only if the line starts with a y.

I tried using the command

```
(Get-Content trial.log2) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "-", 'x'} | Set-Content trial.log2
```

However, it actually replaces all occurrences of the dash, not only for the line the starts with a y.

Can this be also done if I want to have multiple find replace and string manipulation using one get content command?

I have another string manipulation but only if it starts with an F

If line starts with an F, then get first 4 characters of the line, then append 'NEW' then get the next characters from character 20 to 30.

if line starts with a y, then do a replace of - with an X.

```
 $F=(get-content $file) -like 'F*'
  (Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object {
$_ -replace "^F.+", -join("$F".Substring(0,4),   "$NEW3",   
     } | Set-Content trial.log2

Get-Content trial.log2 | ForEach-Object {
  if ( $_ -match '^y' ) {
    $_ -replace '-', 'X'
  }
  else {
    $_
  }
} | Set-Content trial.log3
```

However, if i do this, texts are being written twice. I think there is something wrong with how I look for the line that starts with the F
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a look-behind (`(?<=pattern)`) to assert that the preceding characters include a `y` following the start of the string:

```
(Get-Content trial.log2) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '(?<=^y.*)-','x'} | Set-Content trial.log2
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
Get-Content trial.log2 | ForEach-Object {
  if ( $_ -match '^y' ) {
    $_ -replace '-', 'x'
  }
  else {
    $_
  }
} | Out-File trial.log2.temp
```

Comment: Thanks Bill_stewart and Mathias Jessen. Both of them worked! I've been banging my head on how to do it. I was missing that match command.